# In C#, How can an interface (such as ILogger), with 1 method signature for log(), show 5 on intellisense?

Tags: c#, .net, methods, extension-methods, ilogger

As per the title, how is this done? I understand that the framework has its own class with overloaded extension methods for objects of type ILogger<t>, but what I don't understand is how these methods are exposed through intellisense when the actual interface only has a single definition for log()? How does `var logger = new IloggerClass();` know about the other methods? The reason I am asking is because I created my own extension methods, but they do not show up in intellisense, so I am guessing I am missing something or have the whole concept wrong!

My extension methods are defined with...

```
 public static class LoggerExtensions
    {
        public static void Log<TState>(this ILogger<TState> logger, LogLevel logLevel, string message, int prority)
        {
            //
        }

        public static void LogCustomMessage<T>(this ILogger<T> logger, LogLevel logLevel, string message)
        {
            logger.Log(logLevel, new EventId(), message, null, (state, ex) => state.ToString());
        }
    }
```

I have tried rebuilding/restarting and still no joy.

Comment: Those extra methods are also extension methods from `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerExtensions`. Your extension methods should also show if you have imported the namespace.

Comment: If namespace is the problem its totally ok to put your class with the extension methods in the same namespace as the class/interface you extend. So simply put your class in the "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" namespace.

Comment: Note that you can differentiate between regular methods and extension methods in IntelliSense because extension methods are represented with a down-arrow in front of them.

Comment: @Ralf I changed the namespace to the "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" and it shows up. So even though I had the original namespace in the using statements, it wasn't working. Is this normal behaviour?

Comment: If i understand correctly yes its normal. Its just like with Linq that is in a different namespace then the classes its extend. You might have have all the enumerable namespaces in use but if you don't have System.Linq in the usings you want see the Linq extension methods.